# Is "now as well" correct?

Tags: word-order

I just had a discussion whether it is correct to say:

> This issue should be fixed *now as well*.

I had the impression that `as well` always goes at the end of the sentence but the person I was talking to argued that statements regarding the time must be the very last item in the sentence.

Is this sentence correct? If not, why?

Comment: Your interlocutor is quite wrong: temporal expressions are not confined to the ends of sentences. *Now this issue should be fixed as well*, *This issue should now be fixed as well*, *This issue now should be fixed as well*, *This issue should be fixed as well now*. It depends on where you want to put what sort of emphasis.

Comment: Note that a different use of "as well" does not go at the end. E.g. (as well as): "I like him as well as his friends."

Comment: I would add that you can't locate adverbs (i.e. *now*) in a way that **interrupts** one of the elements of the sentence. This is grammatical: *This issue now should be fixed as well.* but this is not: *`*`This now issue should be fixed as well.*

Comment: Your sentence is fine the way it is. The words "as well" act as part of the complete conjunction ( a conjunction simply connects words, phrases, or clauses) **as well as** [it means *in addition* or *also*]. The conjunction is connecting the word "now" being used as a noun [:the present time or moment --http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/now]. The position has changed by not the meaning. "This issue should be fixed as well now."

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule that, time reference should at the end. It depends on the context.  For ex, I can tell to someone, "don't disturb me, I am going to sleep 'now' ".

Comment: Whatever else, that's an incomplete fragment of thought, which could mean something useful only if what went before was included.

As it is is, which issue should be fixed, and as well as what?

Answer (score -1):

The expression

> as well

can appear anywhere in a sentence and is not limited to the end of a sentence

> *As well* as taste good, it's good for you!
>   It tastes good *as well* as being good for you!
>   It's good for you and tastes good *as well*!

Comment: I believe the main question is about the location of "now", not "as well".

Comment: @M.A.R. I disagree.  The question seems specifically directed towards placement of "as well".

Comment: Not really, Peter. "As well as taste good…" should be "… tasting…" and either way, that's a very different idea from the OP seemed to be asking.